# Fine-tuning values in HTML input range using modifier keys

Tags: html, vue.js, input, slider, user-experience

I'm currently working on an HTML interface that involves using an input range element. In electronic music production, it's common to have the ability to fine-tune control values using special keys like Alt or Shift. From my understanding, it seems unlikely that pure HTML input range supports this feature by default. However, before delving into finding a solution using a framework like Vue.js, I would like to confirm if achieving this functionality is possible in pure HTML.

Additionally, I would prefer to avoid suboptimal solutions that involve using the HTML canvas element. While I'm aware it may be a potential solution, I would like to explore other possibilities first.

Can anyone provide guidance, suggestions, or insights into achieving fine-tuning functionality in pure HTML input range? I would appreciate knowing if it's possible before embarking on a Vue.js-specific solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process the mouse events yourself:

```js
const prop = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf($range), 'value');
const _set = prop.set;
prop.set = function(val){
  if(val < $range.min){
    val = $range.min;
  }else if(val > $range.max){
    val = $range.max;
  }
  $value.textContent = val;
  _set.call($range, val);
};
Object.defineProperty($range, 'value', prop);

let control = false;
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  e.key = 'Control' && !e.repeat && start && (control = true) && setStart(event);
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  e.key = 'Control' && (control = false);
});

$range.value = 0;

const width = $range.offsetWidth;

let start, startVal;
let event;

const setStart = e => {
  start = e.pageX;
  const rect = $range.getBoundingClientRect();
  const val = (start - rect.left) / rect.width * 1000;
  $range.value = startVal = val;
}


$container.addEventListener('mousedown', setStart);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  
  event = e;
  
  if(!start){
    return;
  }
  
  let delta = e.pageX - start;
  if(control){
    delta = delta/10;
  }
  
  
  const rect = $range.getBoundingClientRect();
  delta = delta / rect.width * 1000;
  
  $range.value = startVal + delta;
  
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {

  start = null;

});
```

```css
input{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Audio settings:</p>

<div>
  <div id="$container" style="display:inline-block">
  <input id="$range" type="range" id="volume" name="volume"
         min="0" max="1000">
         </div>
  <label for="volume">Volume</label>
  <div id="$value"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it works with float value? I mean you would have step="1" which become ".1"

Comment: multiply your range by 100 and then divide the input value by 100 to get a float as a result

Comment: unfortunatly it doesn't work like expected. I mean the mouse isn't "slowed down". the value entered seems based on the mouse position. I think I will need canvas to do that. thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @snoobdogg fixed, enjoy, and don't forget to accept my answer (the checkbox) and upvote it (the arrow up) so i would be motivated to help you in the future, thanks

Comment: @snoobdogg it doesn't work if you press Ctrl and start moving the mouse, but you got the idea, i hope